# Sorting JS array by dates DD/MM/YY format

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I`have this type of sting:

12/07/2015|Comment1,11/09/2015|Comment2,31/07/2015|Comment3,30/07/2015|Comment4,
 16/07/2015|Comment5,09/07/2015|Comment6,"

I`m trying to achive this result:

09/07/2015|Comment6,12/07/2015|Comment1,16/07/2015|Comment5,30/07/2015|Comment4,31/07/2015|Comment3,11/09/2015|Comment2,

My code so far looks like this :

```
function rearangeDates(old_order){

            var list = old_order.split(',');
            list = list
                .map( // for each element in the list (each date)
                function(val,idx){
                    // use the first part(before the dot(.)), replace the - with spaces and convert to date
                  console.log(val.split('|')[0].split("/").join("-"))
                    return new Date(val.split('|')[0].split("/").join("-").replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
                })
                .sort(); // at the end sort the results.
        console.log(list)
        }
```

My main objective is to arrange the dates but this function results in :

> [ Fri Jul 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time),
>       **Fri Sep 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) *-> This should be at the end of the array since Sep is after Jul*,**  Invalid Date,  Sun Jul 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time), 
>   Thu Jul 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time),  Thu Jul 16
>   2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time),  Thu Jul 30 2015 00:00:00
>   GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)]

Comment: @Yetti99: `split` can also take a string as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a compare function to your [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

```
.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
})
```

That should sort your dates in the right order.

The `sort` will then order the 2 passed values based on the return value of this function:

> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined